# Range query on secondary index in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cql3

I am using cassandra 2.1.10.
So First I will clear that I know secondary index are anti-pattern in cassandra.But for testing purpose I was trying following:

```
CREATE TABLE test_topology1.tt (
    a text PRIMARY KEY,
    b timestamp
) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = '{"keys":"ALL", "rows_per_partition":"NONE"}'
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'}
    AND compression = {'sstable_compression': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE';
CREATE INDEX idx_tt ON test_topology1.tt (b);
```

When I run following query it gives me error.

```
cqlsh:test_topology1> Select * from tt where b>='2016-04-29 18:00:00' ALLOW FILTERING;
InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="No secondary indexes on the restricted columns support the provided operators: 'b >= <value>'"
```

while this [Blog](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/a-deep-look-to-the-cql-where-clause) says that allow filtering can be used to query secondary index.
Cassandra is installed on windows machine.

Comment: The two answers in this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35718851/how-to-perform-query-with-cassandras-timestamp-column-as-where-condition) that are not yours explain that range queries are not possible on secondary indexes. The post you are referencing also explains that >= restrictions in secondary index queries are only possible for non-indexed columns and only if you allow filtering.

Comment: @Ralf one of the answer also says allow filtering will allow range queries. Also the blog of cassandra I mentioned in the question and this so post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34540883/cassandra-range-search-on-secondary-index-with-allow-filtering suggest the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Range queries on secondary index columns are not allowed in Cassandra up to and including 2.2.x. However, as the post *[A deep look at the CQL WHERE clause](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/a-deep-look-to-the-cql-where-clause)* points out, they are allowed on non-indexed columns, if filtering is allwed:

> Direct queries on secondary indices support only =, CONTAINS or
> CONTAINS KEY restrictions.
>
> [..]
>
> Secondary index queries allow you to restrict the returned results
> using the =, >, >=, <= and <, CONTAINS and CONTAINS KEY restrictions
> on non-indexed columns using filtering.

So, given the table structure and index

```
CREATE TABLE test_secondary_index (
     a text PRIMARY KEY,
     b timestamp,
     c timestamp 
);
CREATE INDEX idx_inequality_test ON test_secondary_index (b);
```

the following query fails because the inequality test is done on the indexed column:

```
SELECT * FROM  test_secondary_index WHERE b >= '2016-04-29 18:00:00' ALLOW FILTERING ;
InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="No secondary indexes on the restricted columns support the provided operators: 'b >= <value>'"
```

But the following works because the inequality test is done on a non-indexed column:

```
SELECT * FROM  test_secondary_index WHERE b = '2016-04-29 18:00:00' AND c >= '2016-04-29 18:00:00' ALLOW FILTERING ;

 a | b | c
---+---+---

(0 rows)
```

This still works if you add another index on column `c`, but also still requires the `ALLOW FILTERING` term, which to me means that the index on column c is not used in this scenario.

Answer (score 3):

The range query **DOES** work with secondary index using **ALLOW FILTERING**

```
cqlsh:spark_demo> create table tt (
              ...     a text PRIMARY KEY,
              ...     b timestamp
              ... );
cqlsh:spark_demo> CREATE INDEX ON tt(b);
cqlsh:spark_demo> SELECT * FROM tt WHERE b >= '2016-03-01 12:00:00+0000';
InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="No supported secondary index found for the non primary key columns restrictions"
cqlsh:spark_demo> SELECT * FROM tt WHERE b >= '2016-03-01 12:00:00+0000' ALLOW FILTERING;

 a | b
---+---

(0 rows)
cqlsh:spark_demo>
```

Comment: can you please confirm cassandra version, cql version and OS. Because it's not working on windows cassandra 2.1.10

Comment: Cassandra 3.3, OS = Mac OS X 10.11.1 El Capitan

Comment: I will have to check for 3.0 or above because this is not working in 2.1.

Comment: @doanduyhai how does this internally work ? whats the data-structure for secondary index? Is it a B Tree? or is it a hidden table with primary key 'b' ? I assume secondary index is created in every node.If so, this query perform some kind of scatter-gather operation on all the nodes ?

Answer (score 0):

This will get you your desired results.  Use b as a clustering column.

CREATE TABLE test_topology1.tt (
    a text,
    b timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY (a, b)
)

select * from tt where b>='2016-04-29 18:00:00' allow filtering;

Comment: I know it will. what I am looking for is why the range query is not working on secondary index with allow filtering when blog says so