# Cassandra schema - select by frequently updated column

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-3.0

Given table:

```
CREATE TABLE T (
      a int,
      last_modification_time timestamp,
      b int,
     PRIMARY KEY (a)
);
```

I'm frequently updating records. With each update `last_modification_time` is set to `now()` and also other fields are set.

What is the right cassandra approach to be able to query by `last_modification_time` range? I need to query like this:

- `select * from .. where a=Z and last_modification_time < X and last_modification_time > Y;`

One way would be to create materialized view with `PRIMARY KEY (a, last_modification_time)` but I want to avoid this since **materialized views are buggy** in 3.X cassandra versions.

What would be alternative way of querying by `last_modification_time` range given `last_modification_time` is frequently updated?

Comment: your schema will result in wide rows... if you cannot change data model and will be always using partition key try secondary index... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35719985/range-query-on-secondary-index-in-cassandra

Comment: @undefined_variable could you clarify what do you mean by  'wide row'?

Comment: Your best alternative is probably to use Postgres to support a query model like this.

Comment: In this case last_modification_time is updated around 20 times then record becomes stable. Given this constraint do you see any data model supporting range queries on last_modification_time?

Comment: @undefined_variable secondary indexes wont work - range queries are not allowed on indexed columns

Comment: Another approach would be to use last_modification_time_one_hour_bucket instead of last_modification_time, then delete record if last_modification_time fits into new bucket and insert a record with new bucket

Comment: @MichalWegorek Wide row was my mistake... But according to link provided cassandra 3.x does provide inequality clause on secondary index (Not tested myself)

Comment: @undefined_variable Inequality is not enough to do range queries. I tested 3.9 cassandra, range queries on indexed columns and not supported

Answer (score 0):

How about having two tables? One could hold the current snapshot where you're updating the `last_modification_time` field and another one which holds the changes over time (something like a history table)? You could write to both of them using `BATCH` statements.

```
CREATE TABLE t_modifications (
      a int,
      last_modification_time timestamp,
      b int,
     PRIMARY KEY (a, last_modification_time)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (last_modificaton_time DESC);

BEGIN BATCH
      UPDATE T SET last_modification_time = 123, b = 4 WHERE a = 2;
      INSERT INTO t_modifications (a, last_modification_time, b) values (2, 123, 4);
APPLY BATCH;
```

If you're interested on the latest snapshot by a given modification range, you can select and limit the `t_modifications` table:

```
SELECT * FROM t_modifications WHERE a = 2 AND last_modification_time < 136 LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, to do range queries like this, the field you want to range on has to be part of the composite key, has to be the right-most element of the composite key, and all other elements in the composite key have to be specified.  In your case, you would modify your PRIMARY KEY to (a, last_modification_time).  You can then

```
SELECT * from t_modifications 
 WHERE a = aval
   AND last_modification_time > beg
   AND last_modification_time < end;
```

This will get you all records for *aval* between *beg* and *end*.